# Java paint() slower in browser?

Tags: java, performance, graphics, applet

Ive made a applet but it runs 4 times slower when i embed it into a webpage compared to the netbeans applet viewer, any ideas why?

example: 6000 fps in netbeans but 1500 fps in browser... O_o

Comment: Applets are basically slow and clunky

Comment: The JVM in use is probably entirely different. Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: I'm amazed your vision can tell the difference.

Comment: *"when i embed it into a webpage"* Why embed it into a web-page at all?  Launch it from a link inside a frame (using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info)) & you might find the performance rises again.  (Not that I can see why an animation needs 1500 FPS, let alone 6000 FPS - AFAIU the human eye is only capable of detecting up to around 120-150 FPS).

Comment: Andrew- I'm making a game so with the 6000 fps before rendering it ends up at 500 fps after. With the other start fps my game has 10 fps. That obviously isn't acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its a good idea to put animation on web page using an applet. Applets are better employed for static use or connectivity such as network connection.

Every time you run your applet, browser has to fetch your class file, provide the required libraries and then load.

Comment: What would you recommend instead as a base then so that I can make a game which is embedded in a web page?

Comment: Flash based games are very popular and work excellent on websites.